# Light travels a straight line write down the principle in which this is manitested

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation

Light traveles a straight line write down the principle in which this is manifested.

Comment: Concerning v2, I would say that the tags 'light', 'optics', and 'variational-principle' are more appropriate than 'homework'.

Comment: is this a homework question?

Comment: Clarify "manitested"?  If typo, please fix.

Comment: It's also nice to show what you've tried, what did or didn't work with your approach, and a 'please' at the end also help in posing a  question.

Comment: Should "manitested" be "manifested"?

Comment: The answer to the question(v4) is [Fermat's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_principle).

Answer (score 2):

[Principle of least action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action); or more specifically [Fermat's principle of least time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_principle).  The least time traveled at a constant speed (first postulate of special relativity) between two points in a flat geometry is a straight line as can be simply shown with variational calculus.

Comment: To be clear, doesn't this only require a local minimum?  After all, light can loop fully around a black hole before making it to its target.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Zassounotsukushi: Yes.  The principle of least action/least time are more accurately called stationary action/time with the classic example of light going from A into a mirror and reflecting to point B, being more time then light going straight from A to B.  See Feynman chapter vol 1-26 or 2-19.  But they are still commonly known as 'least' even though its a bit of a misnomer.

Comment: @Jimbob, it's spelled "principle" - "principal" is a director of the high school. ;-)

Comment: @Lubos: Silly typo from quickness (I know the distinction; as evidenced by the 5 other times principle was spelled correctly before you mentioned this).  While we are pointing out typos, we should we fix: Nuradeen's two spelling mistakes of "traveles" to "travels" and "manitested" to "manifested" and poor overall grammar.

Comment: Not sure what the downvote is for. In case anybody is confused, this is a correct answer.

Comment: @Colin: I have no idea either.  Yes, I didn't particularly elaborate on it and just gave links to wikipedia, but a more detailed answer wasn't really needed.  I guess the c is constant is typically the second postulate of SR.